# TypeScript Intersection Types in Abstract React Component State Causes Readonly Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been trying to make an abstract component in React without breaking the rules of TypeScript's type system too much. According to the typings for React, if state is set in the constructor of a component, it must be complete (all required attributes assigned). One option is to have a child class set the entire state, including the values defined by its parent class. To avoid the duplication that would result, I tried to make it so that the child class can pass this information up to the abstract class. This results in a Readonly error that makes little sense to me. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import * as React from 'react';

function intersect<T1 extends Object, T2 extends Object>(o1: T1, o2: T2): T1 & T2 {
    let merged: any = {};
    // Do anything to merge objects.
    return merged;
}

interface AbstractState {
    example: boolean;
}

abstract class IntersectionStateComponent<S> extends React.Component<undefined, AbstractState & S> {
    constructor(props: undefined, childState: S) {
        super(props);
        let baseState: AbstractState = {
            example: true
        };
        this.state = intersect(baseState, childState);
    }

    render() {
        return <div></div>
    }
}

abstract class NonIntersectComponent extends React.Component<undefined, AbstractState> {
    constructor(props: undefined) {
        super(props);
        let state: AbstractState = {
            example: true
        }
        this.state = state;
    }

    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }
}
```

In `NonIntersectComponent`'s constructor, when the state is set, no error occurs. Assigning `AbstractState` to `Readonly<AbstractState>` is recognised as valid. On the other hand, `IntersectionStateComponent` will not compile, claiming:

```
IntersectionProblem.tsx(19,9): error TS2322: Type 'AbstractState & S' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<AbstractState & S>'.
```

What is the difference that the intersection type is making here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216376/reactjs-typescript-how-to-extend-state-interface

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
this.state = intersect(baseState, childState) as Readonly<AbstractState & S>;
```

---

Keep in mind that what you are doing is an anti-pattern. React recommends using composition over inheritance.

> "At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t
>   found any use cases where we would recommend creating component
>   inheritance hierarchies."

More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html